# Iterating on hash using `each` not like expected

Tags: perl, function, hash, iteration

I am writing a Perl script and have written a subroutine to check whether a key exists in my hash. This is the content of the subroutine:

```
sub _check_existence {
    my $lib = $_[0];
    while( my( $key, $value ) = each (%{$MyHash{sub_keys}})) 
    {
        if ($key =~ $lib)
        {
            return 1;
        }   
    }
    return 0;    }
```

The problem is that every time the function is running it starts from the last time it ran.

For example, if the hash has keys `0` `1` `2` `3` `4` `5` `6` `7` `8`, the first time the subroutine is called looking for the key `3` it will find it. But if I call the subroutine again looking for `3` I will get *false*, because the iteration continues from `4`, and not from the beginning.

Can someone explain what causes this?

Comment: `$key =~ $lib` will in general test whether `$key` *contains the substring` in `$lib`. It will also do some strange things if `$lib` contains any of the regex metacharacters ``\`` `|` `(` `)` `[` `{` `^` `$` `*` `+` `?` `.`. You probably just want a test for string equality `$key eq $lib`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem with `each` in that, as you have discovered, it keeps an internal state for each hash that remembers where the iteration has reached

You can reset that state by a call to `keys %MyHash`, so your subroutine becomes

```
sub _check_existence {

    my ($lib) = @_;

    while ( my ( $key, $value ) = each %{ $MyHash{sub_keys} } ) {
        if ( $key =~ /$lib/ ) {
            keys %{ $MyHash{sub_keys} };
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

However, what you have written is a subroutine that checks whether any of the keys of the hash *contains* the passed parameter as a *substring*, which is an odd requirement. If you meant instead to check for equality then you should be using the essential property of a hash—that it is indexed by its keys, and there is a built-in operator for that: you can write

```
exists $MyHash{sub_keys}{$_[0]};
```

If you really did mean to check for a substring rather than simple equality then there is another option. You never use `$value`, so you can just ask for a list of *keys* of the hash. The `keys` operator doesn't have the same problem as `each` because it isn't designed to return the next key/value pair each tim it is called in scalar context. So you could write this

```
sub _check_existence {

    my ($lib) = @_;

    for my $key ( keys %{ $MyHash{sub_keys} } ) {
        return 1 if $key =~ /$lib/;
    }

    return;
}
```

Finally I would say that using the global `%MyHash` from inside the subroutine is a bit ugly. It should be passed by reference as another subroutine parameter